# How to pass pk argument from url into view in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am having issues passing the pk from the URL into my view. I had this working before when all the URL's paths were situated in the same file but due to poor structure of files I had to re-organise things. I cannot figure out why this is no longer working. Details do exist as I've hard-coded the PK in the view and everything was displayed. It is probably something simple but would really appreciate some help.

URL - http://127.0.0.1:8000/club_home/1/

index.html

```
    <h2>Our Clubs</h2>
    {% for club in all_clubs %}
    <a href="{% url 'clubs:club_home_with_pk' pk=club.pk %}">
        <li>{{ club.club_name }}</li>
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', views.club_home, name='club_home'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.club_home, name='club_home_with_pk'),
url(r'^edit/$', views.edit_club, name='edit_club'),
```

]

views.py:

```
def club_home(request, pk=None):
if pk:
    club = ClubInfo.objects.filter(pk=pk)
elif request.user.is_authenticated:
    club = ClubInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
# photo = model.club_logo.ImageField(storage=profile_pics)
args = {'club': club,
        }
return render(request, 'club_home_page.html', args)
```

club_home_page.html

```
     <h3>Club Details</h3>
<p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for info in club %}
<li>{{ info.club_name }}</li>
<li><img src="{{ info.club_logo }}" height="50px" width="50px"/></li>
<li>{{ info.club_address1 }}</li>
<li>{{ info.club_address2 }}</li>
<li>{{ info.club_address3 }}</li>
<li>{{ info.club_town }}</li>
<li>{{ info.club_county }}</li>
<li>{{ info.club_country }}</li>
</p>
```

View for player registration:

```
class RegisterPlayer(APIView):
renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
template_name = 'player_registration.html'

def get(self, request):
    serializer = PlayerRegistrationSerializer()
    return Response({'serializer': serializer,
                     })

def post(self, request):
    serializer = PlayerRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(template_name='player_registration_complete.html')
```

Comment: What isn't working now? What error do you get?

Comment: Exception Value: 
local variable 'club' referenced before assignment - This happens when I set pk=None e.g. def club_home(request, pk=None):   and this error: Exception Value: 
club_home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk' - When I don't set pk = to anything e.g. def club_home(request, pk):

Comment: Well, for starters I don't know why you didn't put that in the question, but what is confusing you about it? What are you expecting club to be if the user is not authenticated?

Comment: Apologies Daniel, So in my index I have a list of available clubs, if the user (does not need to be authenticated) selects a club it will pass the pk to the url and return the home page for that club providing the details. When a user with a registered account clicks on the club_home tab without a pk it will render their club details instead but it always looks for the pk first. If that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Yes but there is a third case, when the user does not supply a PK *and* is not authenticated. In that case, you don't define `club`, and that appears to be what is happening here.

Comment: Hi Daniel I understand what you mean and I will cater for this. But for the time being, do you happen to have a solution as to why the pk isn't being passed to the view to begin with when the user selects a club?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your URL patterns. Specifically, your "club_home" pattern is too generic; it matches everything, including the case when a PK is provided.

You should always terminate your patterns if you are using the `url()` form:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.club_home, name='club_home'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.club_home, name='club_home_with_pk'),
    url(r'^edit/$', views.edit_club, name='edit_club'),
]
```

If you are using a recent version of Django, you could use `path` instead:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.club_home, name='club_home'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.club_home, name='club_home_with_pk'),
    path('edit/', views.edit_club, name='edit_club'),
]
```

Comment: Daniel that's brilliant did the job,  thanks very much really appreciate your time and help. Gavin

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, as a sign to future searchers that it solved your problem.

Comment: Accepted, Daniel you've been very helpful and I am just wondering would you be able to point me in the right direction to some documentations to carry out my next step. I want to carry on that URL which includes that pk originally selected by the user into other URL's e.g. *** path('<int:pk>/', include('clubkit.player_register.urls'), name='club_player_register')  ***  then the included URL is  ***    path('player_registration/', views.RegisterPlayer.as_view(), name='player_registration'),*** Do you know of a way or any documentation that can accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, does that not work already?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am just struggling with calling that pk now in my player registration view. Error -  
Reverse for 'player_registration' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['club_home/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/player_register/$'] - I have included this view in the question.

Comment: Sounds like you should open another question.

Comment: Just to explain quickly, I have multiple clubs, a user selects a club then all the sub-pages in the nav bar e.g. player registration, club roster etc. when clicked upon will only show features/information based on the club originally selected. Hope this makes a bit more sense.

Comment: I have opened previous questions with no luck not sure if I am not wording the issue correctly